# clone button is missing in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfvc

I have been tasked to move a repository from Azure Devops to a Bitbucket server. I'm very new to Azure Devops. When I went to my repository in Azure, I noticed that I can download the repo as a zip file but there were no options to clone. I downloaded the zip file and when I tried to unzip the file, I got the following message:

```
unzip: can't find file table
```

The unzip process won't complete successfully. Will somebody explain to me why I cannot unzip a file from Azure Devops or tell me why the 'clone' option is missing?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the "Repo" tab, where you're downloading the repository?

Comment: @DanielMann I hope that is enough of a screen shot.

Comment: There's no clone button because it's not a Git repo. It's a TFVC repo. To get a copy of the source code, use `tf` to map a workspace on your machine.

Comment: Hi BidRod How is your issue progressing?Does my workaround meet your request?If you have any question ,please let me know :)

Answer (score 6):

As Daniel Mann said in the comment, there is no clone button in tfvc repo.

To get a copy of the source code ,besides using tf.exe, you can also map a worksapce through visual studio. You can map your source control folder to a single local folder.
You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/create-work-workspaces?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts).
[image]

In addition ,download code repo to a zip file and import it to the new domain is also a way. I tested the downloading as zip and it can be successfully unzip with 7-Zip.

Comment: Hi @Hugh does that mean there is no way to open a tfvc repo in Visual Studio code?

Comment: @Rob Sedgwick You can install Azure Repos Extension for Visual Studio Code.This extension allows you to connect to Azure DevOps Services and provides support for TFVC. You can refer to this [docs](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/git/)